# How to connect meteor and mongoDB on separate machines

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to connect the Mongo DB on the other server with meteor on my local machine.

Any help appreciated.I am new to meteor.

error on running meteor

> Can't start Mongo server.                      MongoDB had an
>   unspecified uncaught exception. This can be caused by MongoDB being
>   unable to write to a local database. Check that you have permissions
>   to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does not support filesystems like
>   NFS that do not allow file locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the meteor app machine, on the server side use this piece of code.

```
 if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.startup(function () {
       var myDatabase = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("<mongo url>");
       MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("collection_name", { _driver: myDatabasee });
     });
   }
```

The only you need to know its the name of the `url <mongo url>`  it could be something like `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local or meteor`

Comment: Can't start Mongo server. MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception. This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database. Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.

Comment: After running the above code . I am getting this Error

Comment: Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.     
Can't start Mongo server.                     
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database.
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does
not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.
                                              
/home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206

Comment: Run Meteor reset 1 time